# How to implement a SARIMA-GARCH model?

Tags: time-series, arima, garch

I was reading ["Prediction of daily peak electricity demand in South Africa using
volatility forecasting models"](https://www.ufs.ac.za/docs/librariesprovider22/mathematical-statistics-and-actuarial-science-documents/technical-reports-documents/teg414-1872-eng.pdf?sfvrsn=b43cf921_0) by C. Sigauke and D. Chikobvu about electricity demand forecasting and I'm interested in reproducing the model they claim to use: SARIMA-GARCH and the Reg-SARIMA-GARCH. There is no code linked to the paper and I'm struggling to see how one would go about using that model with modern programming languages such as R/Python/Julia.

Are there any open resources that go about this implementation of this model?